# Export view sql using `with`

Tags: sql, mysql, join, common-table-expression

I have local db, it's working. This db has views and tables.
and now i wanna import it to server, everything is alright. but when import one view to server got problem, cz the relation to create view little complex and idk where the fault. i try to import back to localhost and no any problem. other table success to import to server.

Database Server:

- Server version: 10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u2 - Debian 9.13
- Protocol    version: 10

---

code to create trouble *view* :

```
    CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = `bm`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vw_kerja_praktek` AS WITH
    tkp AS(
    SELECT
        COUNT(`trn_bimbingan`.`id`) AS `total_bimbingan`,
        `trn_bimbingan`.`id_kp` AS `id_kp`
    FROM
        `trn_bimbingan`
    GROUP BY
        `trn_bimbingan`.`id_kp`
)
SELECT
    `a`.`id` AS `id`,
    `a`.`lokasi` AS `lokasi`,
    `a`.`tgl_mulai` AS `tgl_mulai`,
    `a`.`tgl_akhir` AS `tgl_akhir`,
    `a`.`keterangan` AS `keterangan`,
    `a`.`status` AS `status`,
    `a`.`cek_koordinator_by` AS `cek_koordinator_by`,
    `a`.`komentar_koordinator` AS `komentar_koordinator`,
    `a`.`dosen_pembimbing` AS `dosen_pembimbing`,
    `a`.`status_seminar` AS `status_seminar`,
    `a`.`tanggal_seminar` AS `tanggal_seminar`,
    `a`.`komentar_dosen_pembimbing` AS `komentar_dosen_pembimbing`,
    `a`.`nilai_akhir` AS `nilai_akhir`,
    `a`.`created_by` AS `created_by`,
    `a`.`created_date` AS `created_date`,
    `a`.`updated_by` AS `updated_by`,
    `a`.`updated_date` AS `updated_date`,
    `b`.`name` AS `name`,
    `c`.`name` AS `dosen_name`,
    IFNULL(`d`.`total_bimbingan`, 0) AS `tot_bimbingan`
FROM
    (
        (
            (
                `trn_kerja_praktek` `a`
            LEFT JOIN `vw_user` `b` ON
                (`a`.`created_by` = `b`.`user_id`)
            )
        LEFT JOIN `vw_user` `c` ON
            (`a`.`dosen_pembimbing` = `c`.`user_id`)
        )
    LEFT JOIN `tkp` `d` ON
        (`a`.`id` = `d`.`id_kp`)
    );
```

Error result :

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'tkp as (
select
    count(`trn_bimbingan`.`id`) AS `total_bimbingan`,
' at line 2
```

==========

**All tables for to reproduce issue :**

table trn_bimbingan

```
CREATE TABLE `trn_bimbingan` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_kp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tanggal_bimbingan` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `komentar` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `trn_bimbingan`
--

INSERT INTO `trn_bimbingan` (`id`, `id_kp`, `tanggal_bimbingan`, `komentar`, `created_by`, `created_date`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2023-06-03', 'ok', 'koordinator', '2023-06-03 17:08:05'),
(2, 1, '2023-06-03', 'okasd', 'koordinator', '2023-06-03 17:08:24'),
(4, 3, '2023-06-03', 'ok', '111.11.2205', '2023-06-03 17:30:34'),
(5, 5, '2023-07-04', 'Persiapkan Laporan dengan detail', '111.11.2206', '2023-06-04 02:49:35'),
(6, 7, '2023-06-06', 'p1', '111.11.2206', '2023-06-06 05:35:37');
```

table trn_kerja_praktek

```
CREATE TABLE `trn_kerja_praktek` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lokasi` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_mulai` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgl_akhir` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `keterangan` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('Diajukan','Diterima','Ditolak') DEFAULT NULL,
  `cek_koordinator_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `komentar_koordinator` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `dosen_pembimbing` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_seminar` enum('Belum Diajukan','Diajukan Seminar','Seminar Disetujui','Seminar Ditolak','') DEFAULT 'Belum Diajukan',
  `tanggal_seminar` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `komentar_dosen_pembimbing` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `nilai_akhir` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `trn_kerja_praktek`
--

INSERT INTO `trn_kerja_praktek` (`id`, `lokasi`, `tgl_mulai`, `tgl_akhir`, `keterangan`, `status`, `cek_koordinator_by`, `komentar_koordinator`, `dosen_pembimbing`, `status_seminar`, `tanggal_seminar`, `komentar_dosen_pembimbing`, `nilai_akhir`, `created_by`, `created_date`, `updated_by`, `updated_date`) VALUES
(1, 'km', '2023-06-03', '2023-06-30', 'tes', 'Diterima', NULL, NULL, '111.11.2206', 'Seminar Disetujui', '2023-06-30', 'ok', NULL, 'koordinator', '2023-06-03 00:00:00', NULL, NULL),
(2, 'PT Tes ', '2023-06-04', '2023-07-09', 'tes', 'Ditolak', 'koordinator', 'Gak Betul ini', NULL, 'Belum Diajukan', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'koordinator', '2023-06-03 00:00:00', NULL, NULL),
(3, 'PT. ABC', '2023-06-01', '2023-06-30', 'Tes', 'Diterima', NULL, NULL, '111.11.2205', 'Seminar Disetujui', '2023-06-17', 'OK', 'A', '0011', '2023-06-03 00:00:00', NULL, NULL),
(5, 'PT Serba bisa', '2023-07-01', '2023-09-30', 'Magang untuk tugas KP', 'Diterima', NULL, NULL, '111.11.2206', 'Seminar Disetujui', '2023-10-05', '', 'A', '0011', '2023-06-04 00:00:00', NULL, NULL),
(6, 'PT. JAYABAYA', '2023-06-06', '2023-06-13', 'SURVEY SERTA PENGENALAN TEMPAT KEGIATAN', 'Diterima', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Belum Diajukan', NULL, NULL, NULL, '0012', '2023-06-05 00:00:00', NULL, NULL),
(7, '1', '2023-06-06', '2023-06-13', '2', 'Diterima', NULL, NULL, '111.11.2206', 'Seminar Disetujui', '2023-06-07', 'ok', 'A', '0011', '2023-06-06 00:00:00', NULL, NULL);
```

table view vw_user

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`bm`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vw_user`  AS SELECT `a`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, `a`.`password` AS `password`, `a`.`name` AS `name`, `a`.`role_id` AS `role_id`, `a`.`android_access` AS `android_access`, `a`.`web_access` AS `web_access`, `a`.`secure_ask` AS `secure_ask`, `a`.`is_locked` AS `is_locked`, `a`.`is_nonactive` AS `is_nonactive`, `a`.`created_by` AS `created_by`, `a`.`created_date` AS `created_date`, `a`.`updated_by` AS `updated_by`, `a`.`updated_date` AS `updated_date`, `a`.`ip` AS `ip`, `b`.`role` AS `role` FROM (`utl_user` `a` join `utl_role` `b`) WHERE `a`.`role_id` = `b`.`role_id` ;
```

tabel utl_user :

```
CREATE TABLE `utl_user` (
  `user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `android_access` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `web_access` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  `secure_ask` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `is_locked` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `is_nonactive` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `created_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `utl_user`
--

INSERT INTO `utl_user` (`user_id`, `password`, `name`, `image`, `role_id`, `android_access`, `web_access`, `secure_ask`, `is_locked`, `is_nonactive`, `created_by`, `created_date`, `updated_by`, `updated_date`, `ip`) VALUES
('0011', '$2y$10$6bS0rcJ4CA24gEGbOJAaoud1heiCNeEk4.DbF865W9N5OoHQeWcAq', 'Mahasiswa 1', 'default_icon4.png', 4, b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0011', '2023-06-06 06:55:29', ''),
('0012', '$2y$10$KvODBMvc1Ajv5wdxTC/l2.xeW0kZ7RHdCnpT9Wfl/Ob/JKKIz7ijW', 'Mahasiswa 2', 'default_icon3.png', 4, b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0012', '2023-06-06 06:38:08', ''),
('0013', '$2y$10$4YU0k12wdnRVOOEYf1lVYO/Cc/hJLSBTtXSkdq3oN7.ufuy3qxyKS', 'Mahasiswa 3', NULL, 4, b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'koordinator', NULL, ''),
('0014', '$2y$10$rAReA9YockVtW.yBbiXWgunGIB9PbyveNVqJEavBNTfGVooZUtExi', 'Mahasiswa 4', NULL, 4, b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, ''),
('111.11.2205', '$2y$10$5nyOdRj.0iJXdAVTm7zJke7v863Xo6b05deAMxGZqDgPRZ4nTY1eW', 'Dosen 1', 'default_icon1.png', 2, b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'koordinator', '2023-06-06 06:32:55', ''),
('111.11.2206', '$2y$10$wqaddr.hBnnlJEsj2bOP0eJ5RgQ8Akj5sqhEaCFeDycgEJZvjEFYy', 'Dosen 2', 'default_icon2.png', 2, b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'koordinator', '2023-06-06 06:34:58', ''),
('koordinator', '$2y$10$wqaddr.hBnnlJEsj2bOP0eJ5RgQ8Akj5sqhEaCFeDycgEJZvjEFYy', 'Koordinator', 'default_icon.png', 1, b'0', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'0', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'koordinator', '2023-06-06 05:40:51', '');
```

tabel utl_role

```
CREATE TABLE `utl_role` (
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `utl_role`
--

INSERT INTO `utl_role` (`role_id`, `role`, `description`, `created_by`, `created_date`, `updated_by`, `updated_date`, `ip`) VALUES
(1, 'System Administrator', 'Berkuasa Penuh Atas Aplikasi', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(2, 'Dosen', 'Docter', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(4, 'Mahasiswa', 'patient', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE scripts for all tables for to reproduce your issue.

Comment: ralated tabel and view, updated in the question.

Comment: Table `vw_user` not added.. PS. https://dbfiddle.uk/2MYPZ8aQ After fixing this problem the view is created successfully. https://dbfiddle.uk/UPrtegAv Please report what is **precise** DBMS version - maybe it is too old and does not support CTEs?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? You need 8.0 to use a CTE.

Comment: update in question ; database version

Comment: there is `vw_user` in my question @Akina, the result is do nothing https://dbfiddle.uk/NKTwrEE-, but actually error in real query,,

Comment: Is CTE available in MariaDB? MariaDB starting with 10.5. mine in server 10.1, so sad.. btw thanks..

Comment: *Is CTE available in MariaDB?* Yes, from 10.2.2.

Comment: Probably Version 10.1 doesn't support CTE. Did you try converting it to a subquery instead?

Comment: yap, ongoing converting into subquery

Comment: i'm creating another view for table tkp as `vw_tkp` then in the trouble view, just call that `vw_tkp`.. and viola,, done. idk if this more slow,, hope not..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write that with a subquery instead of CTE as:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED /* DEFINER = `bm`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */ VIEW `vw_kerja_praktek` AS 
SELECT
    `a`.`id` AS `id`,
    `a`.`lokasi` AS `lokasi`,
    `a`.`tgl_mulai` AS `tgl_mulai`,
    `a`.`tgl_akhir` AS `tgl_akhir`,
    `a`.`keterangan` AS `keterangan`,
    `a`.`status` AS `status`,
    `a`.`cek_koordinator_by` AS `cek_koordinator_by`,
    `a`.`komentar_koordinator` AS `komentar_koordinator`,
    `a`.`dosen_pembimbing` AS `dosen_pembimbing`,
    `a`.`status_seminar` AS `status_seminar`,
    `a`.`tanggal_seminar` AS `tanggal_seminar`,
    `a`.`komentar_dosen_pembimbing` AS `komentar_dosen_pembimbing`,
    `a`.`nilai_akhir` AS `nilai_akhir`,
    `a`.`created_by` AS `created_by`,
    `a`.`created_date` AS `created_date`,
    `a`.`updated_by` AS `updated_by`,
    `a`.`updated_date` AS `updated_date`,
    `b`.`name` AS `name`,
    `c`.`name` AS `dosen_name`,
    IFNULL(`d`.`total_bimbingan`, 0) AS `tot_bimbingan`
FROM
    (
        (
            (
                `trn_kerja_praktek` `a`
            LEFT JOIN `vw_user` `b` ON
                (`a`.`created_by` = `b`.`user_id`)
            )
        LEFT JOIN `vw_user` `c` ON
            (`a`.`dosen_pembimbing` = `c`.`user_id`)
        )
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(`trn_bimbingan`.`id`) AS `total_bimbingan`,
        `trn_bimbingan`.`id_kp` AS `id_kp`
    FROM
        `trn_bimbingan`
    GROUP BY
        `trn_bimbingan`.`id_kp`
) `d` ON
        (`a`.`id` = `d`.`id_kp`)
    );
```

Comment: #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: @BudiMulyo, hmm MariaDB seems to be quite restricting. Sorry I don't use MariaDb but postgreSQL.